# Why do I get white highlights at the edge once light build complete?

Tags: unity, lighting, unreal-4, unreal, lightmap

Whenever I build my lights in Unreal, why do I always get white highlights at the edges? I can't seem to solve this. I get this problem with both static and stationary lights. Can someone please help? I have also seen this problem in Unity and I could not solve it.

-Kumsan-

[image]

Comment: I believe this could be a lightmap issue, do you create your own lightmap or use the engines built in render?

Comment: i am using the engines built in since i hit build lighting. have you encountered this issue before?

Comment: yes i have, i encountered it in my college course building a game and the team i worked with to build our fps game in unity. The issue was fixed when we used dynamic lighting instead of fixed, although this does mean creating your own lighting systems etc as i believe unity 5 and unreal engine both use static light maps. I might be wrong but as of a year ago our solution was to build dynamic light maps.

Comment: Is that room a solid single piece of geometry, or is it three "walls" positioned close to eachother in the editor?

Comment: @JoshPetrie three walls positioned close to one another. i am using the basic cube geometry from ue4

Comment: @KumaresanSandran try making the walls overlap with the floor and the ceiling. I got the same artifacts when I had little gaps in-between. I'm not sure it's the same for you though.

Comment: @Sergey.quixoticaxis.Ivanov thats what i thought at first. but then my walls are overlapping correctly. there are no gaps